# How do I see if a double contains a given integer number?

Tags: java, double, contains

I am attempting to find a given integer in a double. I tried the code
 `return String.valueOf(number).contains(digit);`
but received an error saying:

> int can not be converted to CharSequence.

Can someone help me fix this? Or is there a different line of code that does essentially the same thing?

Full code

```
//This method returns true if the double number contains the int digit
//for example, 1.123231312313 does not contain 4, but it does contain 3
public static boolean containsDigit(double number, int digit) {
    return String.valueOf(number).contains(digit);
}
```

Comment: `digit` is not a character sequence, it's a number. You want the string representation of the digit, use `String.valueOf(digit)`

Comment: You also have to convert the **digit** parameter to string, to check if it is part of the converted **number**.

Answer (score 2):

```
return String.valueOf(number).contains(String.valueOf(digit));
```

Just as the error says you're trying to give the contains function an int